# The image can not be rendered using send_file in IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendfile

I have used a controller action for dynamically rendering image files from a url with the following method:

```
send_file( image_url,  :disposition => 'inline',  :type => 'image/jpeg',  :x_sendfile => true )
```

Images are not showing up in IE:

> **Error:Unable to decode image at URL: http://filepathurl.com**

Any help appreciated
thanks

Comment: for uploading which gem you are using ??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message when I tried to open images from localhost. I resolved it by adding localhost to Trusted sites and setting security level Low for it (when "Unsigned ActiveX controls will not be downloaded" disapears from level description)

Comment: This approach sounds not reasonable to end users. Is there any other alternative?